# How to solve "'app name' is not a registered namespace"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a "NoReverseMatch" error. How can I solve this?

#### File *Project_name/urls.py*

```
path('orders/', include('orders.urls')),
```

#### File *ordres/urls.py*

```
from .views import chack_out
path('chack_out/', chack_out, name='chack_out')
```

#### File *ordres/views.py*

```
def chack_out(request):
    .....
```

#### File *product(anther app name)/templates/product/cart.html*

```
<form action="{% url 'orders:chack_out' %}" method="POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
```

#### Error page

[image]

Comment: Either you add `namespace='orders'` to your Project_name/urls.py file or you remove `orders:` from your ...Project_name/urls.py file if the name is unique.

Comment: yes name is unique but how can i right i don't understand ,plz say in code...

Comment: Are you sure this isn't caused by the many misspellings? *"ordres"* vs. `path('orders/'`. `anther`  vs. [`another`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/another#Determiner). `chack_out` vs. [`check_out`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/check_out#Verb)  What misspellings are actually in the code and what are only here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the desired namespace to the `urls.py` file:

```
path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
```

or set the `app_name` attribute inside the `ordres/urls.py` file:

```
from .views import chack_out

app_name = 'orders'
urlpatterns = [
    path('chack_out/', chack_out, name='chack_out')
]
```

Check out the documentation for [URL namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

Comment: it's come type error :   TypeError: _path() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'

Comment: Sorry, namespace is the second argument of include. I changed the answer.

Comment: it's work after adding app_name = 'orders' in "ordres/urls.py" and addnig "path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders'))," in "Project_name/urls.py". but  thx for helping